# Reference datasets for conditional density estimation

Tags: dataset, computational-statistics, density-estimation, conditional

*[In case you feel inclined to close this question because I'm asking for a dataset - I'm looking for solutions in the spirit of point 2 (on-topic) in the accepted answer to [this question about asking for datasets on CVMeta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/questions-about-datasets-possible-exceptions/2097#2097).]*

I am looking for reference datasets to showcase conditional density estimation.

Many statistical libraries ([statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/datasets/index.html), [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html), ...) inlude a collection of datasets that are often used as reference datasets when specific methods are discussed. While I have seen these used in many instances for classification and regression, I have hardly seen any of them be used in conditional density estimation.

There is the [Iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) for classification, the [California housing dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/camnugent/california-housing-prices) for regression – is there a similar dataset (or perhaps even a list of them) for the problem of conditional density estimation? If there is a dataset that may not be a very common reference but it otherwise lends itself particularly well to the task of showcasing conditional density estimation, that would also be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use either of those datasets, no? In Iris, you could estimate the conditional density of the petal length given all the other features (or a subset of them). What are you looking for beyond that?

Comment: I'm trying to find out if there is a reference dataset that's a typical showcase for conditional density estimation. (I agree that one could use one of these datasets in the same way as one could perform classification with the California housing dataset, or regression with Iris, but that wouldn't be what they are typically used for.)